# Sorting Array which is a Value in A Hash in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

I'm trying to sort an **array** which is a value in a **hash**. The following line of code:

```
sort @{ $hash{$item}{'lengths'} };
```

produces the following error:

```
Useless use of sort in void context at ...
```

Answer (score 8):

In Perl, [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) does not modify the array; it returns a sorted list.  You have to assign that list somewhere (either back into the original array, or somewhere else).

```
@{ $hash{$item}{'lengths'} } = sort @{ $hash{$item}{'lengths'} };
```

Or, (especially if the array is deep in a nested hash):

```
my $arrayref = $hash{$item}{'lengths'};
@$arrayref = sort @$arrayref;
```

Your original code was sorting the array, and then throwing away the sorted list, which is why it produces that warning.

**Note:** As [salva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385184/sorting-array-which-is-a-value-in-a-hash-in-perl/4385377#4385377) pointed out, by default `sort` does a string comparison.  You probably wanted a numeric sort, which you get by using `sort { $a <=> $b }` instead of just `sort`:

```
my $arrayref = $hash{$item}{'lengths'};
@$arrayref = sort { $a <=> $b } @$arrayref;
```

But that has nothing to do with the warning message you asked about.

Answer (score 3):

Perl's [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) does not re-order the list "in-place". It actually makes a copy of the list and then sorts and returns . so do it as [cjm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385184/sorting-array-which-is-a-value-in-a-hash-in-perl/4385333#4385333) suggested,

you can read the similar problem on this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/How_to_ask_a_software_question#Example) (*see the example part*)

Answer (score 2):

Note also, that if you are sorting lenghts, you will have to use a numeric comparison:

```
my $lengths = $hash{$item}{'lengths'};
@$lengths = sort { $a <=> $b } @$lengths;
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried something like this

```
my %lrn_hash;

$lrn_hash{1} = 1;
@{$lrn_hash{1}{VALS}} = (6,7,1,5,7,9);

@narr = sort @{$lrn_hash{1}{VALS}};
print "@narr\n";
```

and it worked fine and the output was

```
1 5 6 7 7 9
```

Wich perl version u are using ?

Comment: You didn't get a warning because you didn't use `sort` in void context.  The warning is produced when you don't have the `@narr =` before the `sort`.